# Checkbox array not returning value

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I have a checkbox array that returns values correctly in development but not in production. In production, it returns an array with the number of elements corresponding to the number of elements that were checked, but the value on each is empty. In development I get the string(s) that are assigned to the value of the checkboxes (the ones that have been checked). Here's the relevant html:

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="ckRole[]" value="Fisherman" /> Fisherman</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="ckRole[]" value="Seafood Supplier" /> Seafood Supplier  </li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="ckRole[]" value="Industry Representative" /> Industry Representative</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="ckRole[]" value="Regulator-Elected Official" /> Regulator/Elected Official</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="ckOther" value="Other" /> Other (explain) <input type="textbox" name="txtOther" id="txtOther" /></li>
</ul>
```

And the code:

```
$contact->profession = "";
if(isset($_POST['ckRole'])) { 
//  echo ("<pre>" . print_r($_POST['ckRole']) . "</pre>"); 
    $contact->profession = implode("|", $_POST['ckRole']); 
}
if(isset($_POST['txtOther']) && (!empty($_POST['txtOther']))) {
    $contact->profession .= ((empty($contact->profession) ? '' : '|') . 'Other (' . $_POST['txtOther'] . ')');
}
```

Can't figure out why it works on my test machine but not production. I saw one post that said to add enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form tag, but that didn't help.

Comment: Based off the code you show, there is nothing that would cause values to be empty. In your production environment do you sanitize your data, ie. `stripslashes($_POST)` or `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST)` or ...?

Comment: Did not sanitize. But your response started me thinking. I also have textboxes on the form that use the default value as a prompt. On focus I have a jquery script that removes the prompt and only replaces it on blur if a value has not been assigned. The jquery selector was 'input'. I changed it to 'input[type=text]' and that solved the problem. Also, as it turned out, it wasn't development vs. production. I develop on a Mac but was testing using a PC and that's what caused the alternate behavior. So thanks for the nudge - it did the trick.